# vim mintty/putty mapping <C-Tab> <C-S-Tab>

Tags: vim, tabs, mapping

Under my gvim I use <C-Tab> and <C-S-Tab> to switch buffers. However in my vim under cygwin/mintty these mapping don't work.

If I try the <C-V><C-Tab> with `$vim -u NONE`, I get this:

`[1;5I` for <C-Tab>

`[1;6I` for <C-S-Tab>

How can I make mappings for such key codes ?

Moreover, If I do `:unmap <C-Tab>` and press Ctrl+Tab in normal mode, I go to insert mode.

Any clue ?

Comment: In case that help: `man mintty` say that Ctrl+Tab and Shift+Ctrl+Tab allow switching between sessions (when you have multiple mintty windows opened). 
I have not found how to unbind this and repurpose those key combinations yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set the [terminal's keycodes to vim's keycodes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim) like this:

```
set <c-tab>=^[[1;5I
```

Or you may have to find an unusable key, like `<f13>`, and map it to the terminal code and then map that key to `<c-tab>`. Like so:

```
set <f13>=^[[1;5I
map <f13> <c-tab>
map! <f13> <c-tab>
```

Now I must warn you this approach may not work if your terminal does not send a unique key code to vim.

I personally would simply avoid such a mapping and use something like `[b` and `]b` to move through buffers. Tim Pope's [Unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) provides these exact mappings and a few more very handy mappings.

Alternatively I would suggest against moving through buffers one at a time. There are better ways to go directly to a buffer:

- If you know you are returning then set a capital mark e.g. `mA` and return with `'A`
- Use `<c-6>` to go to the previous buffer (known as the alternative buffer)
- Use ctags/cscope to jump directly to where you want to go via `<c-]>`
- `:b` and `:sb` can take partial filenames and globs. e.g. `:b foo` and `:b foo*bar`
- Use a plugin that helps find a buffer. [CtrlP](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) provides a fuzzy finder for buffers

For more help see:

```
:h tags-and-searches
:h cscope
:h ctrl-6
:h m
:h :b
```

Comment: `set <c-tab>=^[[1;5I` returns `E518: Unknown option: <c-tab>=^[[1;5I`.  I have tried both typing characters out and also `Ctrl-v` to type `^[`. Any idea why? I am using vim 7.4.285 and mintty (cgywin)

Comment: How did you type `^[`? Did you type `<c-v><esc>`?

Comment: I tried that too and type the rest to make the output to be <c-v><c-tab> and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me.
MinTTY uses Ctrl+Tab and Shift+Ctrl+Tab for switching sessions (when you have multiple mintty windows opened). 
So first, you need to disable that behavior by going into the Options > Keys. There you disable the option related to Ctrl+Tab.
Then your vim configuration should work.

Note, instead of using the options menu of mintty, you can also add `SwitchShortcuts=no` to `~/.minttyrc` to disable this shortcut.

I found those instructions on the [mintty wiki](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/blob/master/wiki/Tips.md), which has a section on Ctrl+Tab in screen.